# Only one texture per mesh

Tags: mesh, texturing, materials, uv, texture-baking

I am new to blender. I wanted to import de_train from CS 1.6 to an game engine, but there is too much textures and the engine only support one per mesh. Could anyone help me, or link me a tutorial on how to keep only one, because the engine does not support more then 1 texture.

[Map download OBJ / DE_TRAIN](https://mega.nz/file/j7okiQKR#aPJrW_acR8pFYan0EX1pLfMlxwEzOVxWbSacz7yy23E)

Also, please try your solution if posible before posting here. Thank you in advance :)